# How can I tell all Angular commands are complete from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following to detect when my page has finished loading, but it is evidently wrong. The Angular stuff has not been executed yet when document.readyState is complete:

```
    page.open(url, function (status) {
function checkReadyState() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var readyState = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.readyState;
        });

        if ("complete" === readyState) {
            // onPageReady();
            doRender();
        } else {
            checkReadyState();
        }
    });
}

checkReadyState();
```

});

Comment: you need to work with promises the checkReadyState function needs to return a promise

Comment: If you need to run something in angular after the app has started, put it in .module('app').run

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the purpose exactly but you can use $timeout inside angular code which gets executed only after all execution is finished for that particular angular page, and pass a **global** method which is defined inside your javascript code.
Something like this-

Inside JS file -

```
var callBack = function(){
    console.log('I have finished execution');
}
```

Inside Angular Controller -

```
$timeout(function(){
     callBack();
});
```

If it doesn't solve your problem please elaborate more.

Comment: I have a Javascript program that is reading a webpage. It needs to know when the webpage is completely loaded, including all the angular directives on the page.